# Why can you vote to reopen your own question?

Tags: support, status-bydesign

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254697/) on SO, it closed, which I can understand and if that is the will of the community. However it was also nominated for reopening. I realized that I could click on the link, so tried it, assuming that I would get the "You can't do this" message, but my vote counted.

Why can you vote to reopen you own question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq), you can vote to open or close your question, once you have 250 rep. The amount of rep could be different based on the site, but I believe currently they are all at 250 for this ability.

Comment: guess it is by design then, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Voting to close my own question is possible and very usefull. When somebody tells me that I just introduced a duplicate, but the question already has upvoted answers, I insert a comment on "Voting to close the question myself" and do so. This usually prevents being voted down, as it shows your good will.

Voting to close and reopen is limited to once per question, even if a close/reopen war is going on. And you need 4 people to join with you. So I do not see a problem with one close/reopen vote for my own question.